# Is there any way to get the properties of objects stored in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, javascript-objects

I was taking input from html text box and storing the values in an object with multiple properties there are 2 functions **addAddress** and **displayAddressDetails** functions code are below addAddress is for adding data and displayAddress is for displaying. I am unable to display the data for the different objects.

```
var AddressArray=[];
var l=0;
```

*Adding the address to the object array and clearing the inputs in html textbox*

```
    function addAddress()
    {
      let address = {
         name:document.getElementById("name").value,
         doorNumber:document.getElementById("doorNumber").value,
         streetName:document.getElementById("streetName").value,
         city:document.getElementById("city").value,
         state:document.getElementById("state").value,
        country:document.getElementById("country").value
     };
     //Pushing objects in array
     AddressArray.push(address);

    address={};

    document.getElementById("name").value="";
    document.getElementById("doorNumber").value="";
    document.getElementById("streetName").value="";
    document.getElementById("city").value="";
    document.getElementById("state").value="";
    document.getElementById("country").value="";
    console.log(AddressArray);
    l++;
   }
```

Now I want on pressing a button in HTML all the data as per it is stored in object array should be displayed
*Displaying the address on pressing a button*

```
function displayAddressDetails()
{
  for(let i=0;i<=l;i++)
   {
     for(let item in AddressArray[i])
         console.log(valueOf(item));
   }
}
```

Comment: What issue are you having? What is not working and why?

Comment: please format your code. Use something like jsfiddle to help us understand better

Comment: for properties you can also do Object.keys(array[i])

Comment: I want to print the values of each properties stored in object

Comment: What does `valueOf` do? Why not just do `console.log(JSON.stringify(AddressArray, null, 2))`?

Comment: I was using valueof() just to get the value of the property of the current object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to iterate over object properties:

```
function displayAddressDetails()
{
  for (const item of AddressArray) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
      // do your magic here
    }
  }
}
```

To display a single entry:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
  document.getElementById(key).value = value;
}
```